# Issue Loading Custom Transformer in PySpark Pipeline with a foundry_ml Model: No stage_transform registered for stage

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, serialization, palantir-foundry

I have created a custom FeatureExtractor transformer class in PySpark and successfully trained a machine learning model using a Pyspark Pipeline that includes this custom transformer, along with other transformers and an estimator.  When I initialize and save a `foundry_ml` Model using the stages in this pipeline, no errors are raised, but I'm encountering an issue when I try to load the saved `foundry_ml` model and use it to transform new data.

I get the following error message when attempting to load the saved `foundry_ml` model:

`foundry_ml_core.stage.flexible._flexible_stage.FlexibleStageException: No stage_transform registered for stage type: <class 'myproject.datasets.<MODEL_NAME>.FeatureExtractor'>`

I am using Python 3.8, Pyspark 3.2.1

---

A minimal example of the code for my custom FeatureExtractor class and the main model training function can be found below:

```
# Import necessary libraries and modules for serialization
import cloudpickle

# Import modeling, stage registration, and serialization modules from foundry_ml
from foundry_ml import Model, Stage
from foundry_ml.stage.flexible import stage_transform, register_stage_transform_for_class
from foundry_ml.stage.serialization import deserializer, serializer, register_serializer_for_class

# Import utility functions for data handling
from foundry_object.utils import safe_write_data, load_data

# Import necessary classes from PySpark
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, Transformer
from pyspark.ml.clustering import BisectingKMeans
from pyspark.ml.feature import Imputer, StandardScaler, VectorAssembler

# Import required functions from transforms package
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output


# Define the main model training function
@transform(
    output_model=Output("MODEL_PATH"),
    input_data=Input("INPUT_PATH"),
)
def model_training(input_data, output_model):
    """
    Train a machine learning model using the input data and save the resulting model.
    
    Args:
        input_data (Input): An Input object with the path to the input data.
        output_model (Output): An Output object with the path to save the trained model.
        
    Returns:
        None
    """
    # Register custom stage transforms and serializers
    register_stage_transform_for_class(FeatureExtractor, stage_transform_wrapper, force=True)
    register_serializer_for_class(FeatureExtractor, serializer_feature_extractor, force=True)

    # Instantiate transformers and estimator
    feature_extractor = FeatureExtractor()
    imputer = Imputer(inputCols="features_with_null", outputCols="imputed_features", strategy="median")
    vector_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols="imputed_features", outputCol="unscaled_features")
    standard_scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="unscaled_features", outputCol="scaled_features", withMean=True)
    bisecting_k_means = BisectingKMeans(featuresCol="scaled_features", predictionCol="prediction")

    # Create a pipeline with the defined stages
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[feature_extractor, imputer, vector_assembler, standard_scaler, bisecting_k_means])

    # Get input DataFrame
    df = input_data.dataframe()

    # Fit the pipeline with the input DataFrame
    fit_pipeline = pipeline.fit(df)

    # Create a model with the fitted pipeline stages
    model = Model(*[Stage(stage) for stage in fit_pipeline.stages])

    # Save the model
    model.save(output_model)


# Define custom stage transform function
@stage_transform()
def stage_transform_wrapper(model, df):
    return model._transform(df)


# Define custom deserializer for FeatureExtractor
@deserializer("serialized_feature_extractor_model.dill", force=True)
def deserializer_feature_extractor(filesystem, path):
    return cloudpickle.loads(load_data(filesystem, path, True), encoding="latin1")


# Define custom serializer for FeatureExtractor
@serializer(deserializer_feature_extractor)
def serializer_feature_extractor(filesystem, value):
    path = "serialized_feature_extractor_model.dill"
    safe_write_data(filesystem, path, cloudpickle.dumps(value), base64_encode=True)
    return path


# Define the custom FeatureExtractor transformer class
class FeatureExtractor(Transformer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FeatureExtractor, self).__init__()

    def _transform(self, df):
        # Features are extracted then added as new columns to 'df' here.
        return df
```

The above appears to run successfully. Note that I am able to successfully transform a Dataframe with `fit_pipeline.transform(df)` (not pictured above). Additionally, saving the model does not raise any errors. However, when I try to load the model and transform input data using the following code:

```
# Import Model class from foundry_ml package
from foundry_ml import Model

# Import required functions from transforms package
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output


# Define the model transformation function
@transform(
    input_data=Input("INPUT_PATH"),
    input_model=Input("MODEL_PATH"),
    output_data=Output("OUTPUT_PATH"),
)
def model_transform(input_data, input_model, output_data):
    """
    Transform input data using a pre-trained machine learning model and return the transformed data.

    Args:
        input_data (Input): An Input object with the path to the input data.
        input_model (Input): An Input object with the path to the pre-trained model.
        output_data (Output): An Output object with the path to save the transformed data.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    # Get input DataFrame from input_data
    df = input_data.dataframe()
    
    # Load the pre-trained model from input_model
    model = Model.load(input_model)
    
    # Transform the input DataFrame using the loaded model
    df = model.transform(df)
    
    # Save the transformed DataFrame
    output_data.write_dataframe(df)
```

I get the following error message on `model = Model.load(input_model)`:

`foundry_ml_core.stage.flexible._flexible_stage.FlexibleStageException: No stage_transform registered for stage type: <class 'myproject.datasets.<MODEL_NAME>.FeatureExtractor'>`

---

It seems that the issue is related to the loading of the custom transformer, but I have already registered the custom stage transform and serializer for the FeatureExtractor class in the training program.

For context, I obtained the registration and serialization code using the Palantir Model Integration documentation: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/develop-models/additional-libraries/

Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully load and use the custom transformer in the PySpark pipeline? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> but I have already registered the custom stage transform and
> serializer for the FeatureExtractor class in the training program.

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by this, but generally errors like this can form when the library is not available in the code repository that you're attempting to run, or not loaded properly.

Alongside the documentation linked, there are specific instructions on how to reference the custom stage transform if it is authored within the same repository [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/develop-models/additional-libraries/#configure-the-shared-library)

If the custom stage transform and serializer have been developed in a separate repository, I would follow the instructions [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/share-python-libraries/) and [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/use-python-libraries/) to make sure that you've loaded the external library properly into your repository.

Finally - Getting the exact right import statement to transform to make sure your Class can be referenced within the context of the transform is important. I don't think I see in the code snippet that you posted that specific import statement was included for `FeatureExtractor`, though I'm not sure if you've made sure it's available in the context of your code in a different way